# Class 'GearmanClient' not found. Extension gearman.so installed already

Tags: php, symfony, php-7, symfony-2.7, php-7.0

I am getting below error in my Symfony 2 Application.

`Fatal error: Class 'GearmanClient' not found`

**More Info:**

1. Result from `php -m` lists `gearman`.

   ```
   Meaning: Gearman Extension is installed.
   ```
2. Result from `php --info | grep gearman`:

   ```
   /etc/php.d/40-gearman.ini
   gearman
   gearman support => enabled
   libgearman version => 1.1.12
   ```

   ```
   Meaning: Gearman Extension is installed.
   ```
3. I also made a new file with following code:

   ```
   <?php
     $gmc = new GearmanClient();
     $gmc->addServer('localhost');

     print $gmc;
   ?>
   ```

   which outputs on the webpage:

   ```
   Catchable fatal error: Object of class GearmanClient could not be converted to string in /var/www/test-gearman/gearman.php on line 5
   ```

   There are no errors like `GearmanClient not found`.

   ```
   Meaning: GearmanClient is found by the test application.
   ```

**What I don't understand is:**

Now that gearman extension is installed and GearmanClient is even found by the test application. Why is my symfony application throwing this error.

I am using *supertag/gearman-bundle*.

Thanks in advance. I really appreciate any help.

Comment: I have provided as much info as I thought was necessary. Please do ask for any more details if required.

Comment: You could still add the symfony code from where the error actually comes from? You could try in symfony side with added backslash: `$gmc = new \GearmanClient();` (I couldn't find any documentation explaining why exactly that is needed but this seems to be the way I'm accessing the generic php library classes from symfony)

Comment: It's coming from a composer package. However, I added the backslash and even then it didn't work for me. Still the same error `class GearmanClient not found`.

Also, adding a slash in the beginning would mean, php would check directly in the global namespace for the class.

Comment: ah, yes. Missed the part that you were using a bundle here. So what part of your symfony application is throwing that error? I assume that you have all the bundle settings done according to the bundle instructions (addition to AppKernel etc)?